# How do I create a histogram with labeled groups?

Tags: r, histogram

This is probably a very basic question but I am new to R - I am trying to create a histogram of this data set: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgusU.png)
I coded each age group into values 1-6.
How do I create a histogram of this data where the X-axis has each labeled group ("18-24yrs", "25-34yrs", etc) and the y-axis has their frequency? I know how to create a histogram where my X-axis is just the 1-6 values but I don't know how to make these categorical and keep their frequencies.

Thank you!

I tried creating categorical variables from the code:

```
Age_Cat <- as.factor(
+     ifelse(Screen_Data$Age_Cd == 1 , "18y-24y",
+            ifelse(Screen_Data$Age_Cd == 2, "25y-34y", 
+                   ifelse(Screen_Data$Age_Cd == 3, "35y-44y",
+                          ifelse(Screen_Data$Age_Cd == 4, "45y-54y",
+                                 ifelse(Screen_Data$Age_Cd == 5, "55y-64y",
+                              ifelse(Screen_Data$Age_Cd == 6, "65+y", "Other")))))))
```

But if I do hist(Age_Cat) I get an error.

Comment: `hist(Age_Cat)` uses the entire data frame, you only want to use a single numeric column, `hist(Age_Cat$Age_Cd)`, but if you use `barplot` instead, you can use your formatted column, `barplot(table(Age_Cat$Age))` is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  age_range = c("18 - 24", "25 - 34", "35 - 44", "45 - 54", "55 - 64", "65 +"),
  count = c(1, 3, 6, 6, 3, 1)
)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = age_range, y = count)) +
  geom_col()
```

A histogram is more apropriate for counting the frequency of observations in the dataframe.  Since you already have the counts, you should use a column chart instead and specify the y-axis as your "count/frequency" variable.

You then just need to specify the order you want the x-axis to be in.  Since it's ordinal.  You could do this by specifying the order of the columns and then using a `scale_x_discrete` function or something similar.

*I'm also assuming you're using ggplot2 and the tidyverse syntax framework.  I also made up the numbers so it's not an exact match of the image you originally linked to.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIuDR.png)